# Sequelize join when key is inside a JSONB field

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Is there a way to use include (which is actually a join table) to another Model, where the key is INSIDE a `JSONB` field? for example:

`Item { id: INTEGER, someJsonbField: JSONB }`

(item example: `{ id: 1, someJsonbField: { storeId: 2 } }`)

Then, for getting all of the items of store with id 2, you write something like this:

`Item.findAll({ include: { model: 'Store', key: 'someJsonbField.storeId', ... } })`

OFCOURSE, in a real world scenario, `storeId` should be inside `Item` directly, but only for the purpose of this question - How could it be done?